# Is it possible to change the INPUT language, as you edit a filename in nautilus?

Tags: keyboard, nautilus, shortcut-keys, filemanager

I have some files that must have filenames containing English and Greek letters.

Example:  "CREPALAND 2017-06-30 ΠΡΟΣΦΟΡΑ 33sec".

I am using standard Nautilus with Ubuntu 16.04.

When I am trying to edit the filename, every time I am trying to change the input language, the edit stops and cancels. It's has the same behavior as if I had pressed escape.

So I have to edit the filename 2 times per file, one with each input language.

This is so annoying....

I am using <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> for the input change and I have noticed that the edit stops and cancels as soon as I press the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key.

I have tried to change with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd> also but then the edit stops and cancels as soon as I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> key.

Any ideas? The most annoying thing is that it cancels all the edit, so you have to retype the whole thing for the beginning if you accidentally try to change language...

Comment: What happens if you try to change the layout clicking on the layouts indicator?

Comment: You just clicked away from the file... so it cancels

Comment: Doesn't cancel for me in any of the cases (keyboard shortcut or clicking on the indicator)! I have Nautilus 3.20.4 which comes with pop-up renamer. It looks something like [this](https://i1.wp.com/www.debugpoint.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/GNOME-Files-3.20-Rename.png). You may try using an updated version of Nautilus.

Comment: Seems to be another example of well-known [bug 1244090](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1244090).